# Where is the Excel Object Library file

Tags: excel, object

I'm looking for the Excel Object Library file to import it into LabVIEW.  I have MS Office 2013 installed and can find MSACC.olb, MSOUTL.olb, MSPPT.olb, and MSWORD.olb but can't figure out which file (.olb or .dll) to import in order to manipulate Excel files in LabVIEW.

Comment: The Excel team does it differently. The Excel object library is the executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE

Comment: I have been soooo frustrated looking for a .DLL or a .OLB file to import... thank you so much, it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Excel team does it differently. The Excel object library is the executable:

Office 2013:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
```

Office 2016:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
```