# Delphi - How to import type library for Excel

Tags: excel, delphi

I have just done a complete new install (Windows 10, Delphi Seattle, Office 2016 64 bit).  While I have worked with Office 32 bit before, Office 64 bit is new to me.  I have an existing application I wrote, and I am trying to get the dev environment set up...  I need both the Office_TLB and the Excel_TLB files.  I know to create these via Importing type library.  That went fine for Office, however when I go to Import a Type library for Excel, Excel is NOT listed as one of the 60 or so options.  I did a search for Excel, and it is not there.  It definitely is installed (64 bit only), and runs fine.  How do I create the Library for Excel when it is not showing up as an  option?

Comment: Does this help:[How work with Word and Excel in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44216993/576719)

Comment: And the excel object library seems embedded into the exe file. [Where is the Excel Object Library file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33375425/576719)

Comment: You don't need a separate TLB import unit for 64 bit Excel. Just use the TLB import units that Emba supply.

Comment: @David - I have tried this and there are things that are not defined.  For example, (in my old install) using Delphi Seattle, and Importing the Excel Library from Excel 2013, there is a const defined as xlPivotTableVersion15 (which my app is using).  When I look at the OCX files that Embarcadero supplies, there is Excel2000, Excel2010, and ExcelXP.  I use Excel2010, but the latest const is xlPivotTableVersion14.  I need a more recent Excel Type library, supporting at least Excel 2013.

Comment: But that's nothing to do with 32 and 64 bit. That's an issue relating to using an import unit generated from an older type library. So you may want to generate from a new type library to solve that. But be clear that this is not related to bitness. You will also have to be careful that you are clear as to which versions of excel are supported.

Comment: @David - Thank you for all your help, not only in this issue but other issues you have helped as well.  The issue is that the Type library Import functionality within Delphi does not show Excel 64 bit in the list.  I have been able to create the TLB file manually using the TlibImp command.  This URL shows how:  https://bobsotherblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/import-64bit-type-libraries-in-delphi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to create the TLB file manually using the TlibImp command. It may be due to the fact that Excel is a 64 bit executable, I don't know.  Regardless, this solved my issue.  This URL shows how: https://bobsotherblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/19/import-64bit-type-libraries-in-delphi/